# How to correct HTML syntax due to a string literal error?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I'm adding some HTML code to a servlet but when I paste in the code it, Eclipse throws an error saying that `String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote`.

I tried to fix this by checking the syntax of the block of HTML but it seems to be correct.

Can anyone spot the error in the declaration?

This is the offending piece of code:

```
out.println (
      "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" 
          \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n" +
      "<html> \n" +
        "<head> \n" +
          "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; 
            charset=ISO-8859-1\"> \n" +
          "<title> My first jsp  </title> \n" +
        "</head> \n" +
        "<body> \n" +
          "<font size=\"12px\" color=\"" + color + "\">" +
            "Hello World" +
          "</font> \n" +
        "</body> \n" +
      "</html>" 
    );
```

Comment: That's why you don't write HTML in Java source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to join the lines:

```
out.println ( "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n" + "<html> \n" + "<head> \n" + "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\"> \n" + "<title> My first jsp</title> \n" + "</head> \n" + "<body> \n" + "<font size=\"12px\" color=\"" + color + "\">" + "Hello World" + "</font> \n" + "</body> \n" + "</html>" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two linebreaks, try this:

```
out.println (
      "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" 
          \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n" + // here is linebreak one - error1
      "<html> \n" +
        "<head> \n" +
          "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; 
            charset=ISO-8859-1\"> \n" + // here is linebreak two - error2
          "<title> My first jsp  </title> \n" +
        "</head> \n" +
        "<body> \n" +
          "<font size=\"12px\" color=\"" + color + "\">" +
            "Hello World" +
          "</font> \n" +
        "</body> \n" +
      "</html>" 
    );
```

Corrected:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String color = "";
        String test =
                "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n" +
            "<html> \n" +
              "<head> \n" +
                "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\"> \n" +
                "<title> My first jsp  </title> \n" +
              "</head> \n" +
              "<body> \n" +
                "<font size=\"12px\" color=\"" + color + "\">" +
                  "Hello World" +
                "</font> \n" +
              "</body> \n" +
            "</html>";
        System.out.println(test);
    }
```